# OWC11 PivotTable: TotalMember not supported

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, office-interop

I have an ancient classic ASP app which is using Office Interop for pivots.

All was working fine until I recently had to move to a new host. After a day of suffering I've managed to get CreateObject("OWC11.PivotTable") working.

I'm now trying to run this:

```
Dim oPivot
Set oPivot = Server.CreateObject("OWC11.PivotTable")
'... get data from sql'
set myData = oPivot.ActiveData
set dataColumnMembers = myData.ColumnMembers 
dataColumnMembers.TotalMember
```

It fails on the last statement with this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'dataColumnMembers.**TotalMember**'

I'm guessing the OWC dll I'm using on the new server is newer then the one on the old server and might have *TotlaMember* deprecated. I can't find out what's the replacement.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew, I finally got it working! Here's the solution for OWC11:

These properties

```
myData.ColumnMembers.TotalMember
myData.RowMembers.TotalMember
```

were replaced by

```
myData.ColumnAxis.ColumnMember.TotalMember
myData.RowAxis.RowMember.TotalMember
```

That was a lucky guess :)